# pass datetime in sql query while fetching the data with bulk api simple_salesforce Python

Tags: python, sql, datetime, bulk, simple-salesforce

I have a code that will be running automatically and I need to save the datetime of the last run so that the next time my code runs it only grabs the data that has been updated later than last run time. I am using simple_salesforce library with BULK API call. Here is my code:

```
# open json file and retrieve last_run_time
with open('last_run_time.json', 'r') as openfile: 
    last_run_time = json.load(openfile)
print(last_run_time)
# '2020-05-14T14:48:38Z'

# sql query 
sf_data = sf.bulk.Opportunity.query("SELECT ID FROM Opportunity where CreatedDate > last_run_time AND AdPoint_Id__c <> NULL")

today_date = datetime.now()
today_date_time = today_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"+"T"+"%H:%M:%S"+"Z")

# save datetime in json file, overwriting the old value
with open("last_run_time.json", "w") as outfile: 
    json.dump(today_date_time, outfile)
```

My query throws an error `IndexError: list index out of range`. How can I pass `last_run_time` variable in sql statement?

Comment: which line exactly is throwing the error? and what is Z supposed to do in "%Y-%m-%d"+"T"+"%H:%M:%S"+"Z"?

Comment: @MrFuppes Z is the format of the datetime I have on salesforce end. The query is what throws an error. `where CreatedDate > last_run_time`

Comment: ok you should specify that in the question. as a sidenote, `datetime.now()` returns a naive datetime object representing the timezone of your operating system. if you want to express a UTC timestamp, use `today_date_time = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc).isoformat()` with `timezone` from the datetime module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break out the `last_run_time` variable from the rest of the query string. In the current form, the literal string 'last_run_time' is included in your query.

The amended query would be:

```
sf_data = sf.bulk.Opportunity.query("SELECT ID FROM Opportunity where CreatedDate > " + last_run_time + " AND AdPoint_Id__c <> NULL")
```